# Write the equation of the osculating circle of$ y=\sin(x)$  at $ (\pi/2,1)$

Tags: calculus

I don't understand the concept of parametrization or how to go about solving this question.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you understand radians and trigonometry?  If you understand radians, and the functions Sin(t) and Cos(t), then it should be fairly easy to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The osculating circle is one that passes through the point of interest with the same slope and curvature.  You know the point of interest is $(\pi/2,1)$.  The derivative at this point is $0$, so the tangent is horizontal.  The center of the osculating circle is along the perpendicular to the tangent, which here is the line $x=\pi$, and on the concave side of the curve, below it in this case.  So can you find the equation of a circle, which a) has center along $x=\pi$ and is below $(\pi/2,1)$, b)passes through $(\pi/2,1)$, and c) has the same second derivative value at $(\pi/2,1)$ as $\sin x$?  a) and b) together take care of the tangent.